# Border div inside div isnt respecting sizes

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside other div. The second div is showend only with jquery function with hover.

But i'm having some issues with second div border. Isn't showing complete like the first div.

[image: [image]()]

Here's my css.

First div:

```
#featuresFirst #featuresLeft {
     float: left;
     width: 66%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: yellow;
     margin-right: 5px;
     margin-left: 5px;
}
```

The second div:

```
.featuresInfo {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #6000ff;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v5H2J/1/)

Comment: Please provide more code. We can't understand the problem this way

Comment: Can you post the JS or make a fiddle? From [what you posted](http://jsfiddle.net/dNprj/), there seems to be no problems.

Comment: Already have the fiddle there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

To both #featuresFirst #featuresLeft and .featuresInfo.